# How to find the x,y coordinates of a rotated vector

Tags: javascript, geometry, rotation, trigonometry

I found the best way of calculating the width and height of the bounding box of a vector post-rotation from a different stack overflow post. This worked great. My problem now is calculating the new x,y coordinates of the rotated vector's bounding box. Here is the my javascript. The `newWidth, newHeight` variables are correct -- the `rotatedXPos, rotatedYPos` are not correct, however, and it's because `x0, y0` -- which I think should be the rotating middle of the vector -- are also incorrect (They're set to just the x,y coordinates of the upper-right/left of the vector, which I know is wrong).

```
this.options.rotationAngle = parseInt(this.options.lastRotationAngle);
var degreesAsRadians = this.options.rotationAngle*Math.PI/180;
var points = new Array();
points.push({x:0, y:0});
points.push({x:this.options.width, y:0});
points.push({x:0, y:this.options.height});
points.push({x:this.options.width, y:this.options.height});
var bb = new Array();
bb['left'] = 0; bb['right'] = 0; bb['top'] = 0; bb['bottom'] = 0;

$A(points).each(function(p) {
  var newX = Math.abs(parseInt(p.x * Math.cos(degreesAsRadians) + p.y *  Math.sin(degreesAsRadians)));
  var newY = Math.abs(parseInt(p.x * Math.sin(degreesAsRadians) + p.y * Math.cos(degreesAsRadians)));
  bb['left'] = Math.min(bb['left'], newX);
  bb['right'] = Math.max(bb['right'], newX);
  bb['top'] = Math.min(bb['top'], newY);
  bb['bottom'] = Math.max(bb['bottom'], newY); 
});

var newWidth = parseInt(Math.abs(bb['right'] - bb['left']));
var newHeight = parseInt(Math.abs(bb['bottom'] - bb['top']));

Object.extend(this.options, {
rotatedWidth: newWidth
,rotatedHeight: newHeight 
});

var x0 = this.options.xPos;
var y0 = this.options.yPos;

this.options.rotatedXPos = x0+(this.options.xPos-x0)*Math.cos(degreesAsRadians)+(this.options.yPos-y0)*Math.sin(degreesAsRadians);
this.options.rotatedYPos = y0-(this.options.xPos-x0)*Math.sin(degreesAsRadians)+(this.options.yPos-y0)*Math.cos(degreesAsRadians);
```

[And here is a video.](http://screencast.com/t/MjAxNzZhN) In the video, the red box shows the newWidth, newHeight correctly, but the `rotatedXPos`, and `rotatedYPos` are not being calculated at the top/left of the newly rotated vector. I'd love any help, thanks much!

Comment: You might get better traction here: http://mathoverflow.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know where the center of the ellipse is (xc, yc) then the upper left corner of the bounding box is

```
(xc - newWidth/2, yc - newHeight/2)
```

(assuming +x goes right and +y goes down).

Comment: Thank you sir. A variation of this worked for me:
    var box = this.DiagramNodeVector[0].getBBox();
    this.options.rotatedXPos = (box.x + (box.width)/2) - newWidth/2;
    this.options.rotatedYPos = (box.y + (box.height)/2) - newHeight/2;